# ¿En que fallo al crear el array de tamaño N?

Tags: javascript, array, prompt

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de JavaScript donde he de crear (mediante prompt) un array de tamaño N, introducir valores númericos y verificar que todo sean numeros enteros.

Mi problema es que a la hora de crear el array no me lo crea vacío sino que me introduce el valor del tamaño y no veo que estoy haciendo mal

```js
function esEntero(n) {
    if (isNaN(n)) return false;
    else {
        if (n % 1 == 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}

function array() {
    var n = prompt("Introduce tamaño del array:");
    do
        if (esEntero(n)) {
            var arr = new Array(n);
        }
        else {
            var n = prompt("Error, introduce un valor NUMERICO; ");
            var arr = new Array(n);
        }
    while (esEntero(n) == false);

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr.push(valores());
    }

    arr.sort();

    console.log(arr.length);
    console.log(arr);

}
```

Esta es la función para introducir los valores:

```js
function valores() {
    var x = prompt("Introduce un número: ");
    do
        if (esEntero(x)) {
            var valor = x;
        }
        else {
            x = prompt("Error, introduce un valor NUMERICO; ");
            var valor = x;
        }
    while (esEntero(x) == false);

    return valor;

}
```

Comment: Pues el problema es que al crear el array con el constructor `new Array()` y pasarle un string lo que estás haciendo es crear un array con el valor que le pasas al constructor. El constructor de `Array` en JS reacciona de maneras diferentes en función de lo que le pasas, y de hecho es poco recomendado usarlo precisamente por esas inconsistencias. Si le pasas un `number` te creará un array de n elementos, si le pasas un string te creará un array con el elemento n (que es justo lo que te sucede a ti). Solución: busca otra manera de crear el array o si quieres hacerlo así utiliza el parseInt()

Comment: La mejor manera de crear un array vacío en JS es simplemente crearlo: `let arr = [];` y ya está. Los array son dinámicos en JS, no tendrás problemas en ir haciendo push a un array sin tamaño definido (o técnicamente, con tamaño 0). Incluso puedes coger un array y cambiarle el atributo length "a mano": `arr.length = 0` por ejemplo vacía un array :)

Comment: Te faltan las llaves del do.

Comment: @Benito-B me parece que estás respondiendo en los comentarios... Sería mucho más beneficioso que publicarlas eso mismo como una respuesta.

Comment: @Pollo no considero que mi comentario sea una respuesta válida pues ni aporta ejemplos ni enlaces a documentación ni nada más que una breve explicación. Cuando elaboro una respuesta me gusta hacerlo con tiempo y detalle, de lo contrario prefiero dejar un comentario dando una breve explicación que pueda guiar al autor u otra persona a la respuesta correcta, y ya más tarde si tengo tiempo y me acuerdo, pongo una respuesta si no hay ninguna válida. Pero siéntete libre de usarlo para elaborar una!

Comment: @Benito-B y al mismo tiempo, ese comentario inhibe a otros que quizás hubiesen respondido algo similar. Un comentario es para consultar y repreguntar, no para dar una posible solución. Estás respondiendo, no con la calidad que querrías pero estás respondiendo, y los comentarios no son para eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noob88, acá te dejo una solución, que no habría podido llevar a cabo, sin la guía de @Benito-B

```js
function esEntero( n ) {
    if( isNaN( n ) || n === "" ) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if( n % 1 == 0 && n > 0 ) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function array() {
    var arr = [];
    var n = prompt( "Introduce tamaño del array:" );
    do {            
        if( esEntero( n ) ) {
            arr.length = n;
        }
        else {
            n = prompt( "Error, introduce un valor NUMERICO; " );
        }
    }
    while( ! esEntero( n ) );

    for( var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        arr[ i ] = valores();
    }
    arr.sort();
    console.log( arr.length );
    console.log( arr );
}

function valores() {
    var valor;
    var x = prompt( "Introduce un número: " );
    do {
        if( esEntero( x ) ) {
            valor = x;
        }
        else {
            x = prompt( "Error, introduce un valor NUMERICO; " );
        }
    }
    while( ! esEntero( x ) );    
    return valor;    
}

array();
```

Como verás, primero modifiqué **esEntero**, para que devuelva falso sin recibe un **""**, o un número negativo.
Como el ejercicio te pide que crees un array de longitud **n**, he creado el array y con el valor recibido le asigno un tamaño.
Después, dentro del **else** que está dentro del **do**, he quitado **var arr = new Array(n);**, ya que en esa instancia, sabes que no tienes un número válido (por eso estás dentro del **else**) por lo que no corresponde instanciar el array.
Dentro del **for** he cambiado el push por asignación con **=**, para evitar que el tamaño del array crezca.
Por último en la función **valores** hice la misma modificación dentro del **do**, quitar **var valor = x;**.
Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Habían bastantes fallos que he corregido y ahora te ara lo que esperas...

```
   function esEntero(n) {
        if (isNaN(n)){ 
            return false;
        }else{
            if (n % 1 == 0) { 
                return true;
            }else{ 
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    function array() {
        var n = prompt("Introduce tamaño del array:");
        var arr = new Array(0);
        var repite = false;
        while (repite == false){
            if (esEntero(n)) {
                arr = new Array(n - 1);
                repite = true;
            }else {
                n = prompt("Error, introduce un valor NUMERICO: ");
            }
        }
        var i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var valor = 0;
            repite = false;
            while (repite == false){
                valor = prompt("Introduce el valor NUMERICO para: " + i);
                if (esEntero(valor)) {
                    arr[i] = valor;
                    valor = "";
                    repite = true; 
                }else{
                    valor = prompt("Error, Introduce el valor NUMERICO para: " + i);
                }
            }
        }

        arr.sort();

        console.log(arr.length);
        console.log(arr[0]);

    }
```